# How do I group by and display only first row of each group?

Tags: views

I want to apply aggregation on my view so that only first row of each group should be displayed after group by aggregation.
I have a view with two fields Subject and Due_Date and sorted values like,
Subject     Due_Date
A               2016-03-24
A               2014-06-28
A               2012-10-15

B               2013-11-21
B               2011-10-18
B               2010-03-04

C               2013-07-13
C               2012-12-09

After group by aggregation I want it to have like this,
Subject     Due_Date
A               2016-03-24
B               2013-11-21
C               2013-07-13

It should only have the first row of each group.

I have tried Views aggregator plus, but it is just hiding the values and not eliminating them. With that I couldn't get my filters working the way I need.
Is there any solution for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using D7 - [View Merge Rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) module can provide the functionality that you need.

In your scenario, select field subject as Grouping field Nr.1.

Access Merge setting in Advanced section of your View.

[image]

For the `Subject` field - select the setting "`Use values of this field as a filter`".

For the `Due_Date` field - select the setting "`Use the first value of this field`".

If your View contains more than two fields, you will need to select the settings for `Merge rows` to accommodate processing of added fields.